# NavigationManager.NavigateTo in .NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid not working

Tags: .net, maui-blazor, blazor-hybrid

I am trying to navigate from razor page to razor page but it looks like the Blazor syntax is not working properly for NavigateTo()

```
@page "/"

@using System.Diagnostics;
@inject NavigationManager Navigation;

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="NavigateToPage">GoTo Foopage</button>

@code {
    private async void NavigateToPage()
    {   
        Navigation.NavigateToPage("/foopage", true);
        Debug.WriteLine($"NavigateTo Foopage clicked");        
    }
}
```

```
@page "/foopage"

@using System.Diagnostics;

<h1> Foo Page</h1>

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {   
        Debug.WriteLine($"This is the FooPage");        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The NavigationManager doesn't provide `Navigation.NavigateToPage("/foopage", true);`. You need call the `NavigateTo()` method to navigate to the desired URL. Please change the `Navigation.NavigateToPage("/foopage", true);` to `Navigation.NavigateTo("/foopage", true);` to get it worked like below:

```
private async void NavigateToPage()
{
      Navigation.NavigateTo("/foopage", true);
      Debug.WriteLine($"NavigateTo Foopage clicked");
}
```

Comment: May I know whether your issue has been solved or not? If not, please share it in here. We can work together to figure it out.